# Установить фокус на любой узел в большом svg-документе

Tags: javascript, html, svg

У меня есть большой svg-документ с множеством узлов, краткий пример ниже.

Частью моих требований является наличие меню, в котором вы можете выбрать один из узлов, которые являются шестиугольниками, а затем, чтобы фокус переместился на этот узел или шестиугольник.

Как мне разместить документ на любом узле?

Например, если я нажму кнопку в этом примере, как я могу установить фокус на шестиугольнике, который находится дальше всего справа?

Думаю, я мог бы использовать viewBox, но мне бы хотелось узнать, как этого добиться.

Я мог бы использовать `minX` и `minY`, которые являются первыми двумя аргументами `viewBox`.

Но как мне установить их значения значения?

Могу ли я получить `x` и `y` из значений `getBBox()` узла?

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

let A = -1200;
let B = 1200;

let hexArray = []

function drawHexagon(r){  
  let points = "";
   for( let i = 1; i <= 6; i++ ){
        let a = i * ( Math.PI / 3 );
        let x = (r * Math.cos( a - Math.PI/2 )).toFixed(3);
        let y = (r * Math.sin( a  - Math.PI/2)).toFixed(3);
        points += `${x},${y} `;
      }
  return points;
}

function useHex(theParent,pos){
   let use = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'use');
   use.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#theHex');
   use.setAttributeNS(null,"x",pos.x);
   use.setAttributeNS(null,"y",pos.y);
   //use.setAttribute("title",'x value:'+pos.x);
   theParent.appendChild(use);
   hexArray.push(use);
  
   drawText('x value:'+pos.x,pos)
}

function drawText(val,pos){
  let txt = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'text');
  txt.setAttributeNS(null,"x",pos.x);
  txt.setAttributeNS(null,"y",pos.y);
  txt.textContent = val;
  txt.setAttributeNS(null,"transform",`translate(0,30) rotate(-75  ${pos.x},${pos.y})`);
  textParent.appendChild(txt);
}

function connector(parent,p){
  let path = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'path');
  let d =`M${p.x},${p.y}C${p.x},125 0,125 0,0`;
  path.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d);
  parent.appendChild(path);
}

for(let x = A; x <= B; x+=50){
  let pos = {x:x,y:250}
  useHex(useParent,pos);
  connector(connectors,pos);
}



document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click",()=>{
  alert('how do I focus on a node, including those that are off screen');
});
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}
use {
  fill: white;
  stroke: #000;
}

#itr {
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

#connectors path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}

#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
}

text {
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: end;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">select node</button>

<svg id="svg" viewBox="-600 -50 1200 550" style="--display:block;">
<defs><polygon  id="theHex"  points="21.651,-12.500 21.651,12.500 0.000,25.000 -21.651,12.500 -21.651,-12.500 -0.000,-25.000 "  ></polygon>
</defs> 
<g id="connectors">
  
</g>
<g id="useParent">
<use xlink:href="#theHex" y="0"  />
</g>
<g id="textParent">
  
</g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [set focus to any node in large svg document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54275271/7394871) от участника  [@dagda1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11755/dagda1).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/54275271/7394871

Answer (score 2):

Я добавил атрибуты `tabindex` к элементам `<use>`. Это помогает сфокусировать эти шестиугольники.

Когда вы нажимаете кнопку, вы фокусируетесь на элементе, `tabindex` которого (в данном случае) равен 20. Затем, когда вы нажимаете клавишу табуляции на клавиатуре, вы перемещаете фокус на следующий шестиугольник.

Я установил атрибут viewBox вашего svg в зону значения атрибута `x` сфокусированного элемента.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

let A = -1200;
let B = 1200;

let hexArray = []

function drawHexagon(r){  
  let points = "";
   for( let i = 1; i <= 6; i++ ){
        let a = i * ( Math.PI / 3 );
        let x = (r * Math.cos( a - Math.PI/2 )).toFixed(3);
        let y = (r * Math.sin( a  - Math.PI/2)).toFixed(3);
        points += `${x},${y} `;
      }
  return points;
}

function useHex(theParent,pos){
   let use = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'use');
   use.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#theHex');
   use.setAttributeNS(null,"x",pos.x);
   use.setAttributeNS(null,"y",pos.y);
   use.setAttributeNS(null,"tabindex",pos.i);
   
   theParent.appendChild(use);
   hexArray.push(use);
  
   drawText('x value:'+pos.x,pos)
}

function drawText(val,pos){
  let txt = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'text');
  txt.setAttributeNS(null,"x",pos.x);
  txt.setAttributeNS(null,"y",pos.y);
  txt.textContent = val;
  txt.setAttributeNS(null,"transform",`translate(0,30) rotate(-75  ${pos.x},${pos.y})`);
  textParent.appendChild(txt);
}

function connector(parent,p){
  let path = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'path');
  let d =`M${p.x},${p.y}C${p.x},125 0,125 0,0`;
  path.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d);
  parent.appendChild(path);
}

for(let x = A,i=0; x <= B; x+=50,i++){
  let pos = {x:x,y:250,i:i}
  useHex(useParent,pos);
  connector(connectors,pos);
}

let theButton = document.querySelector('[type=button]')

theButton.addEventListener("click",()=>{
  let index = theButton.value;
  let active = document.querySelector(`[tabindex = '${index}']`)
  active.focus()
  //alert('how do I focus on a node, including those that are off screen');
});


// event listener for keyup
function checkTabPress(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
        let activeElement = document.activeElement;
        let posX = activeElement.getAttribute("x"); 
        svg.setAttributeNS(null, "viewBox", `${posX - 600} -50 1200 550`); 
    }
}


document.querySelector('body').addEventListener('keyup', checkTabPress);
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}
use {
  fill: white;
  stroke: #000;
}


#connectors path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}

#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
}

text {
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: end;
}

use:focus{fill:red}
```

```html
<button type="button" value="20">select node</button>

<svg id="svg" viewBox="-600 -50 1200 550" style="--display:block;">
<defs><polygon  id="theHex"  points="21.651,-12.500 21.651,12.500 0.000,25.000 -21.651,12.500 -21.651,-12.500 -0.000,-25.000 "  ></polygon>
</defs> 
<g id="connectors">
  
</g>
<g id="useParent">
<use xlink:href="#theHex" y="0"  />
</g>
<g id="textParent">
  
</g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54275720/7394871) от участника  [@enxaneta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7897395/enxaneta).</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Если я правильно понимаю, вы хотите увеличить выбранный узел. Как вы писали, это можно сделать с помощью viewBox. Я добавил в ваш код следующий фрагмент:

```
var svg = document.getElementById('svg')
document.getElementById('useParent').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if(evt.target.nodeName === 'use') {
      focusNode(evt.target);
  }
});
function focusNode(node) {
    var bbox = node.getBBox()
    svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `${bbox.x - 250} ${bbox.y - 30} 600 275`)
    node.setAttribute('style', 'fill:red;');
    //TODO: need to clear the previous selection
}
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click",()=>{
  focusNode(hexArray[0]);
});
```

Ширина и высота viewBox уменьшаются вдвое: `600 275` против оригинального `1200 550`. В основном это двукратный зум. И он изменяет `min-x` и `min-y` viewBox, чтобы шестиугольник оказался примерно в центре SVG.

```js
const SVG_NS = 'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg';
const SVG_XLINK = "http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink";

let A = -1200;
let B = 1200;

let hexArray = []

function drawHexagon(r){  
  let points = "";
   for( let i = 1; i <= 6; i++ ){
        let a = i * ( Math.PI / 3 );
        let x = (r * Math.cos( a - Math.PI/2 )).toFixed(3);
        let y = (r * Math.sin( a  - Math.PI/2)).toFixed(3);
        points += `${x},${y} `;
      }
  return points;
}

function useHex(theParent,pos){
   let use = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'use');
   use.setAttributeNS(SVG_XLINK, 'xlink:href', '#theHex');
   use.setAttributeNS(null,"x",pos.x);
   use.setAttributeNS(null,"y",pos.y);
   //use.setAttribute("title",'x value:'+pos.x);
   theParent.appendChild(use);
   hexArray.push(use);
  
   drawText('x value:'+pos.x,pos)
}

function drawText(val,pos){
  let txt = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'text');
  txt.setAttributeNS(null,"x",pos.x);
  txt.setAttributeNS(null,"y",pos.y);
  txt.textContent = val;
  txt.setAttributeNS(null,"transform",`translate(0,30) rotate(-75  ${pos.x},${pos.y})`);
  textParent.appendChild(txt);
}

function connector(parent,p){
  let path = document.createElementNS(SVG_NS, 'path');
  let d =`M${p.x},${p.y}C${p.x},125 0,125 0,0`;
  path.setAttributeNS(null,"d",d);
  parent.appendChild(path);
}

for(let x = A; x <= B; x+=50){
  let pos = {x:x,y:250}
  useHex(useParent,pos);
  connector(connectors,pos);
}

var svg = document.getElementById('svg')
document.getElementById('useParent').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  if(evt.target.nodeName === 'use') {
    focusNode(evt.target)
  }
});

function focusNode(node) {
  var bbox = node.getBBox()
    svg.setAttribute('viewBox', `${bbox.x - 250} ${bbox.y - 30} 600 275`)
    node.setAttribute('style', 'fill:red;')
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener("click",()=>{
  focusNode(hexArray[0]);
});
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}
use {
  fill: white;
  stroke: #000;
}

#itr {
  width: 500px;
  display: block;
  margin: 2em auto;
}

#connectors path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
}

#tooltip {
  position: absolute;
}

text {
  dominant-baseline: middle;
  text-anchor: end;
}
```

```html
<button type="button">select 1st node</button>

<svg id="svg" viewBox="-600 -50 1200 550" style="--display:block;">
<defs><polygon  id="theHex"  points="21.651,-12.500 21.651,12.500 0.000,25.000 -21.651,12.500 -21.651,-12.500 -0.000,-25.000 "  ></polygon>
</defs> 
<g id="connectors">
  
</g>
<g id="useParent">
<use xlink:href="#theHex" y="0"  />
</g>
<g id="textParent">
  
</g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54275907/7394871) от участника  [@Dmitry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2003070/dmitry).</sub>